# SVG fallback for interactive graphics

Tags: html, svg

I am working on an interactive SVG map that is not stored in a separate file, but defined directly in the html file like this:

```
<svg id="map" ...>
    <path  d="M1336.5,2969.1c-10.8 ... "/>
</svg>
```

I want to display old version of the map (div containing plenty of images, each of them changing on hover) in all the browsers not supporting SVG. Is it possible to do without using JavaScript?

So far I've found couple of solutions showing how to use fallback for svg files, for example:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="svg-ok.svg">
  <p class="warning">
    Your browser does not support SVG!
  </p>
</object>
```

But how to do it when both maps are part of the DOM, not just pictures in separate files?

Comment: What browsers are you targetting that don't support SVG?

Comment: @RobertLongson Mostly IE8